# Tensorflow:add the dependencies of the quantization operation to the c_binary in the BUILD file of the label_image program:

Tags: tensorflow

I tried to follow the instructions in "How to Quantize Neural Networks with TensorFlow"  until I find these instructions which I don't know how to do. [Snapsort image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kn2tb.png)

And I got this error when I use the following command:
[Snapsort image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLTtc.png)

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The "Mul:0" name you pass as feed input is not a valid name in the graph.

Comment: I just followed the tensorflow's instructions and I am a novice in tensorflow. How should modify the command in this case?

Comment: It depends on how the original graph was built.